# How to stop a function from being treated as a property in a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, class, object, methods, properties

I have the following object in a javascript (Node.js if it matters) application.

```
function myObject (myInput){
    this.myValue = myInput;
    this.myAssociativeArray = {};
    this.myAssociativeArrayLen = function() {
        var k;
        var l = 0;
        for (k in this.users){
            l = l + 1;
        }
       return l;
    };
}
```

When I call the length function and log it to the console I get this as the output:

```
function () {
    var k;
    var l = 0;
    for (k in this.myAssociativeArray){
        l = l + 1;
    }
    return l;
}
```

I'm really nor sure how this is happening but it appears that the function is being treated as a string property but I don't have quotation marks, so how could this be the case? I've also noticed that the editor I am using (Sublime) is not changing the color of the last this like it does with the others. I'd to have the length function be part of the object so that I can just call myObjectInstance.
myAssociativeArray and the get a length. 
Any help would very appreciated!

Comment: How are you calling the console log? Usually if you get the printed version of a function its because you are not actually executing the function, but referencing it i.e. `console.log(someObject.myFunc)` instead of `console.log(someObject.myFunc())`

Comment: In the first peace `this.users` or `this.myAssociativeArray`? And how do u call the function: `myObject.myAssociativeArrayLen` or `myObject.myAssociativeArrayLen()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that in your console.log, you're not actually running the function and you could be just be referencing it.

```
console.log(myObject.myAssociativeArrayLen());
```

vs (what I think you're doing)

```
console.log(myObject.myAssociativeArrayLen);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to define a property which should be invoked implicitly.
You need to use [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) feature in this case.
However `getter` is not supposed to be used with function constructer as you could write equivalent prototype method shared across all instances.
But still you can add the getter in following way :

```
function myObject(myInput) {
    this.myValue = myInput;
    this.myAssociativeArray = {};
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
            "myAssociativeArrayLen" : { //add the myAssociativeArrayLen property to this instance
                "get" : function() {//define getter
                    //your logic
                    return smthing;
                },
            }
        });
}
var x = new myObject(5);
alert(x.myAssociativeArrayLen);//implicitly invoke the associated getter function
```